# Show Highlight on a UIButton with Subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, calayer

I'm trying to create a UIbutton that has the following characteristics:
* A custom image as its content
* Rounded corners
* A drop shadow

Using the following code will format the button to appear correctly and function but the highlight action (i.e., the darkening of the button when touched) is lost when the touch occurs. Any ideas?

```
+(void) styleButton:(UIButton*)button{
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(button.bounds.origin.x, button.bounds.origin.y, button.bounds.size.width, button.bounds.size.height)];    

    CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
    sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    sublayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;

    sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(button.bounds.origin.x, button.bounds.origin.y, button.bounds.size.width, button.bounds.size.height);

    backgroundView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [backgroundView.layer addSublayer:sublayer];

    [button insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];

    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = sublayer.bounds;
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    imageLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"].CGImage;
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [sublayer addSublayer:imageLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried converting your backgroundView into a UIImage and add it to the button instead of adding backgroundView as a subview? That would preserve the darkening when the button is pressed:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundView.frame.size);
[backgroundView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this (ARC enabled):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.button.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

for (UIView *aView in self.button.subviews) {

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, aView.frame.origin.x, aView.frame.origin.y);
    [aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[self.button setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:YES];
```